# encoding of text by using java code

Tags: java

the my code by using servlet language that read the text line by line and fill string buffer each 5000 words in a string buffer then display the content in jsp page and I put in header display text in utf-8 the problem is when the text in utf-8 encoding the code read it in unkown character and I want my code to read text in utf-8 and the text shown to user in utf-8 encoding
here is my code for reading the text

```
 try{
   File file = new File(p);         
   l = (int) file.length(); 
   String s = null,strr=null;
   String g = null,m=null;
   int i = 0;
   Scanner input = new Scanner(file); 
   s1 = new StringBuffer();
   s2 = new StringBuffer();
   while (input.hasNextLine()) {
     g = input.nextLine();
     String[] d = g.split(" ");
     int h = d.length;
     i = i + h;
     if (i > 5000) {
       break;
     }
     s1.append(g).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
   }
   if(i > 5000) {
     s2.append(g).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
     while( input.hasNextLine()) {
     s = input.nextLine(); 
     String[] d = s.split(" ");
     int h = d.length;
     i=0;
     i=i+h;
     if (i > 5000) {
       break;
     }
     s2.append(s).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));}
     if (input.hasNextLine()) {
       s3.append(s).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
       while(input.hasNextLine()) {
         strr = input.nextLine(); 
         s3.append(strr).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
       }
     }
   }
 input.close(); 
 } catch (Exception e) {
   e.getMessage();
 }
```

Comment: could you please try to use capital letters and punctuation it is complicated to understand the text which is not structured at all thanks in advance ps breaking text into paragraphs could be a neat idea too

Comment: @Andrzej: Yes! :) My brain refuses to parse the question text, producing a scary exception.

Comment: I display the text in another jsp page by using usebean tag

Answer (score 0):

Check the javadocs of the methods you're using - the [Scanner(File)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File%29) constructor lets you know that:

> Bytes from the file are converted into characters using the underlying platform's default charset.

Instead, you can call the [Scanner(File, String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29) constructor to explicitly specify the file encoding:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(file, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: thank you and I tried your answer but there is no result shown

Comment: @user Well that sounds about right, given that you don't have any `println` statements.  Or are you saying you have reason to believe that specifying the character set means that the file is considered empty??

Comment: I display the text in jsp page by using usebean tag .

Comment: and the file is not empty, but when I use your answer the text is not displayed